# Edge case of circular proofs

Tags: proof-theory

I understand the basic idea behind circular proofs and why they are invalid proofs. but I ran into an edge case and I'm not sure how to deal with.

First of all, I'm going to define what it means for a proof to be circular. Let's say we have two claims, B and C. a proof of C which uses the claim B would be called circular, if (and only if) the **only** way to prove claim B, uses claim C. In that case, the proof for C is invalid, because a proof of a claim which uses the claim is invalid (if this definition is diffrent from the formal one, please correct me).

Now for the edge case: Let's consider the case where we have 3 claims: A, B and C, where the only way to prove A uses B, and that C implies B (whether B implies C or not, we don't know. If it makes a difference, please tell me). If I try to prove C with A, would the proof be circular? or valid? According to my understanding, it depends on how we know B is true. if we can prove B without C, or we take B as an axiom, then the proof would not be circular, but valid. But if we can only prove B is true, using the fact that C is true (the exact way doesn't matter), then the proof would be circular.

Is my understanding correct? if not, then why?

Answer (score 1):

It very rarely the case that you can prove $B$ only by using $C$. And if that is the case or not, or if $B$ and $C$ are true, has nothing to to with the proof being circular. A circular proof is *wrong reasoning*, that doesn't mean the conclusions are wrong, or that that is the only way to prove them.

Comment: I agree that circular proof is a wrong reasoning, but it's a specific kind of wrong reasoning. It's  wrong reasoning because you end up using a claim to prove the same claim. This is why I need to highlight the fact that we can only prove B using C, because of you can prove B without C, then you don't end up in need of C for the proof of C. At least how I understand it.